# The program terminates halfway

Tags: c, pointers, struct, stack

i think terminates after the end of the stud()

```
struct stud
{
  int flag;
  char surname[90];
  int semester;
};


int prepush(int *stack,int *head,int *n)
{
 int c,r;
 int *p;
 printf("[1].Add Student\n");
 printf("[2].Add Proffesor\n");
 do
 {
    printf("Pick:");
    scanf("%d",&c); 
    getchar();
 }while(c!=1&&c!=2);
 switch(c)
 {
    case 1:p=stud();break;
    case 2:p=prof();break;
 }
 r=push(stack,&head,&n,p);
 return r;
}
```

i don't know what to return so i can put it in my stack..adress or what

```
int stud()
{
  struct stud a,*p;
  p=(void *)malloc(sizeof(a));
  p->flag=1;
  printf("Give surname:");
  gets(p->surname);
  printf("\nGive semester:")
  scanf("%d",p->semester);
  return p;
}
```

this is how i call it
    r=push(stack,&head,&n,p);

```
int push(int *stack,int *head,int *n,int *p)
{
  if(*head==*n)
    return 0;   
  stack[*head++]=p;
  return 1;
}
```

i actually want to put into a stack pointers that point to structs

Comment: If you're on a 64-bit system you are in big trouble, because then the size of `int` is 32 bits while pointers are 64 bits.

Comment: You still shouldn't use `int` to store pointers.

Comment: so what should i change?

Comment: There is a generic pointer type, used by for example the return type of `malloc`. It's called the void pointer, `void *`.

Answer (score 1):

The three following lines are a major problem:

```
struct stud a,*p;
p=(struct stud *)malloc(sizeof(a));
p=&a;
```

Here you declare two local variables `a` and `p`, allocate memory and make `p` point to it. You the directly afterward *reassign* `p` to point to the `a` variable. That means you loose the memory you allocated in the previous line, and have a memory leak.

What's worse is that you then return this pointer to a local variable, and as you know local variables goes out of scope once the function they were defined in returns. So what will the pointer then point to? Using this pointer leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: okay i see..so what i can put in my stack that will show the struct that i created from stud() what should i return

Comment: @KazaMaster you would need to copy the contents of `a` to the location pointed by `p` then you can return the address of `p` as your code already does. As Joachim pointed out, your current code throws away the allocated memory and lets `p` point to the address of `a` which goes out of scope when function ends.

Comment: i still can't understand what to change so i can store structs to my stack

Comment: @KazaMaster If you have more than one structure you want to store in the stack, you might want to learn about unions.

Comment: can't i store in the stack the adress of its struct?

Comment: @KazaMaster Of course, if you have only a single structure to put on the stack, you can use a simple single-linked list for a stack.

Comment: can i use void pointers that point to structures?..so i can put in my stack void pointers that everytime point in a different structure(stud or prof).

Comment: it must be a way that i can put in a stack...different structures..or pointers that point to structures

Comment: @KazaMaster Yes, the problem with e.g. a stack of `void*` is that you have no idea what's on the stack. You need some way to distinguish the different structure.

Comment: that's why i have flag